# Minima of $\frac{a+b+c}{b-a}$ for a,b,c in $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \geq 0$ and $a < b$

Tags: inequality, quadratics, quadratic-forms

**Problem:** If for every real x, $ax^2 + bx + c \geq 0 $ where a, b, c are reals such that $a < b$, what is the smallest value of $\frac{a+b+c}{b-a}$.

Let $$ L =  \frac{a+b+c}{b-a} $$

I have a solution by two different other methods

**1)** By first using $b^2 - 4ac \leq 0$ and then substituting $b = a + k$, and do some algebraic manipulations, and use AM-GM in between to obtain $L \geq 3$

**2)** By substituting $\frac{b}{a} = t$, do some algebraic manipulations again, then use the fact that $\frac{b^2}{4a^2} = \frac{t^2}{4} \leq \frac{c}{a}$ to obtain a equation solely in $t$ and then just minimise it using calculus to again obtain $L \geq 3$

But I was trying to explore other methods to solve this problem and the following was my attempt at doing so,

Let us say the given is bigger than some constant $k$,

$$ L =  \frac{a+b+c}{b-a} \geq k $$

But $f(1) = a + b + c$ and $f(0) = c$, thus $f(0) - f(-1) = c - (a - b + c) = b - a$ further,

Thus the given is equivalent to,

$$ \frac{f(1)}{c - f(-1)} \geq k$$

$$ \frac{f(0) - f(-1)}{f(1)} \leq \frac{1}{k} $$

I couldn't proceed any further using this method. Any suggestions on how to proceed using this, or any similar methods would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a comment on your successful solutions: You may need to check the directions of your inequalities, because the condition $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$ implies $b^2-4ac \le 0$, the opposite of what you wrote (only the "=" case is the same). But you made the right conclusions.

Comment: Yes I made a error whole typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured another method, which is as follows:

$$ \frac{a + b + c}{b - a} = \frac{3f(1)}{f(1) - f(-2)} \geq 3 $$

Which follows since $f(1) \geq 0$ and the minima will be when $f(-2) = 0$